# How to run a thread infinitely without blocking main thread in c++?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++14, fork

I am trying to make a native app , and I need a separate thread freezing some values(constant overwriting with delay) in the background and I don't need any return from it to main. So after creating the thread when I detach from it , it does not do the freezing.

```
  pthread_create(&frzTh, NULL, freezingNow, NULL);
  pthread_detach(frzTh);
```

But if I join the thread then it performs freezing but my main thread gets blocked as it waits for the child thread to finish , and since the child runs infinitely , there is no coming out.

```
pthread_create(&frzTh, NULL, freezingNow, NULL);
pthread_join(frzTh,NULL);
```

So, I tried using fork() to create a child process instead of thread. Now , I am able to perform all tasks parallel to my main. But , this is causing a lot of memory usage and leads to heating of device.

```
   pid_t pid_c = fork();
      
   if (pid_c == 0 && freeze) {
 
             while (freeze) {
                 Freeze();
                 usleep(delay);
             }
         }
```

So, what is the best way to do this ?

Best example is game guardian app and it's freezing mechanism.

Comment: Do you insists on using pthreds library? Why do you not use C++ native threading?

Comment: @DanielLangr I have also tried that also , I forget to add . Same issue. If I detach , I cannot freeze . If I join my main thread stays blocked.

Comment: What does "freezing some values" mean? Who is producing the new values? Who is observing the frozen ones? What is supposed to happen when a new value is produced during a "frozen" period?

Comment: freezing = constant overwriting a variable . So even if a new number is produced I want to keep writing my number to the variable. @Useless

Comment: How is that different to just writing a variable normally? What was changed by "freezing" it? Does "constant overwriting" mean overwriting it repeatedly with the same constant value, or overwriting it with new values _continually_?

Comment: Constant overwriting = overwriting it repeatedly with same constant value with some sleep duration in between, in case other process which has access to it writes something else to it. So freezing will allow me to keep the value for that variable to what I want , no matter who changes it.

Answer (score 1):

To do this properly, you need to have a mechanism by which the main thread can cause the child thread to exit (a simple `std::atomic<bool> pleaseQuitNow` that the child thread tests periodically, and the main thread sets to true before calling `pthread_join()`, will do fine).

As for why you need to call `pthread_join()` before exiting, rather than just allowing the main thread to exit while the child thread remains running:  there is often run-time-environment code that executes after `main()` returns that tears down various run-time data structures that are shared by all threads in the process.  If any threads are still running while the main-thread is tearing down these data structures, it is possible that the still-running thread(s) will try to access one of these data structures while it is in a destroyed or half-destroyed state, causing an occasional crash-on-exit.

(Of course, if your program never exits at all, or if you don't care about an occasional crash-on-exit, you could skip the orderly shutdown of your child thread, but since it's not difficult to implement, you're better off doing things the right way and avoiding embarrassment later when your app crashes at the end of a demo)

Comment: Exiting is not the problem which I am facing. If I exit from the thread to run other things on main then the continuous overwriting will stop . But , I need that to keep running in background and still be able to work from in my main thread.

Comment: To allow the main thread and the spawned thread to both execute in parallel, you should call `pthread_create()` near the beginning of `main()` and don't call `pthread_join()` until the end of `main()`, when your app wants to exit (after setting `pleaseQuitNow` to true or in some other way telling the child thread to exit)

Comment: I think I should have clarified the way I want my app to work. Best example is game guardian app. It freezes a variable by continuous overwriting for as many variables as you want and the main thread is never blocked.

Comment: Correct.  The only time the main thread should be blocked is when `main()` calls `pthread_join()`, and the only time `main()` should call `pthread_join()` is when the main thread about to exit, so that the child thread can safely exit before `main()` returns and the C++ runtime starts cleaning up the runtime's shared state.

Answer (score 0):

If you wanna do Something as async with Mainthread untill end main ,
I recommand Promise - future in c++

this example :) good luck

```
#include <future>
#include <iostream>
#include <thread> 
void DoWork(promise<int> p)
{
// do something (child thread)
// saved value in p
 p.set_value(10);
}

int main(void)
{
 promise<int> p; 
 auto future = p.get_future();
thread worker{ DoWork, std::move(p)};

// do something you want

// return  result
 int result = future.get();

std::cout<< result <<'\n'; // print 10
}
```

Comment: tried tested , unless I join the thread , I cannot perform overwriting. And joining brings me back to square one . my main gets stuck. @Lucius